# Gradle fail sync Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, gradle

I have this problem. I downloaded this API from https://github.com/tlaukkan/zigbee4java
I tried several times to import the project on Android Studio 2.3.1 but always Gradle fail to sync with this `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`
I read on other posts about this error but I do not understand what to change because this API should be correct. 
Thank You for support.
Best Regards.

EDIT
these are the steps I did:
 - unzip file
 - open Android Studio
 - select Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)
 - I select zigbee4java-master
 - and then Start Gradle Build

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists 
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.StringHelper
buildscript {
repositories {    
    jcenter()    
}     
dependencies {    
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

def zigbee4javaProfilesArray=StringHelper.tokenizeUnquoted(zigbee4javaProfiles)

group = 'org.bubblecloud.zigbee4java'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'build-common.gradle'

/* Include build scripts from all profiles selected in 'gradle.properties' */
allprojects {    
    repositories {    
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repository-bubblecloud.forge.cloudbees.com/release/" 
        maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    }
}
dependencies {
for (zigbee4javaProfile in zigbee4javaProfilesArray) {
    switch (zigbee4javaProfile) {
        case 'android':
            println 'zigbee4java: Including Android build'
            compile project(':zigbee-serial-android')
            compile project(':zigbee-console-android')
            break;

        case 'javase':
            println 'zigbee4java: Including JavaSE build'
            compile project(':zigbee-serial-javase')
            compile project(':zigbee-console-javase')
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope these informations are correct to understand my problem.
Thank You

EDIT
About GRADLE 3.0 problem I tried this:
on Settings I set "Use a local Gradle Distribution" and I set the path to a downloaded Gradle 2.2.1 distribution. But this not solved the problem.
I also tried this uninstalled Android Studio 2.3.1 and Install Android Studio 1.1 with Gradle 2.2.1 by default but again the same problem.

[The problem could be: import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.StringHelper ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCmnk.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe the steps you did *exactly*.

Comment: Post your structure folder

Comment: In docs they say "NOTE: Gradle build is currently broken in 3.0."

Comment: Well, i am little confused, if in the gradle-wrapper.properties is written services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip  what Gradle is used 2.2.1 or 3.X

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem.
I don't say that all my steps are necessary but this is what I did,
Simply I uninstall all Android Studio and all the Android folders under ..\Users\userName\ and under \Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android.
This to be sure to have a clean installation.
After I install Android Studio 2.3.1 patch to 2.3.3 than downloaded necessary Android API (API 21 in my case).
Then in File-> Settings-> Gradle I checked "Use local Gradle distribution" where mi distribution is gradle-2.2.1
At the end I select Import Gradle Project from the Android Studio Start Menu and no Gradle error message appear and everything seem to be imported correctly.

My opinion is that, the first time I tried to import the project using Gradle 3.2. I suppose some files and folder was generated not correctly, so when I tried to use the correct Gradle version the import not work properly.
When I delete everything and used the correct Gradle version the import was successful.

Thanks to all the people that answer to my question, and tried to help me.
Best Regards